# Links does not work in <a href> tag when content has .com inside

Tags: html, email, html-email

in my code I generate a body of a html email message. Part of it is following:

```
<a href="mylink.pl">SomeName.com</a>
```

When I receive this email in my Mail client or in Gmail and when I click the link I'm directed to the `SomeName.com` and not to the `mylink.pl` which is in the href part of the `<a>` tag. And it looks that this situation occurs only for the `.com` domains.

Any ideas how I could deal with this?

Comment: Try using absolute urls as Quentin mentioned. Tongue in cheek, that code snippet seems to be for phishing :-)

Comment: No it's not fishing, we just want to count how many times our users go to different sited from our links, so the link leads to our service, but the user is automatically redirected to the service SomeName.com

Comment: So what you really want is:
`<a href="http://oursite.com/mylink.pl?redir=SomeName.com">SomeName.com</a>`, correct?

Comment: So, it looks like GMail is actually parsing the link text and assuming that it is a web address, and creating a link to `SomeName.com` instead of the target you specified in the `<a>`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 12):

Use absolute URIs in emails. They start with (usually) `http://`

What you have is a relative URI, which doesn't make much sense in an email. You are probably just hitting your browser's search function when you try to visit it.

Comment: there is http://, so basically the code is following:
<a href="http://www.mylink.pl">SomeName.com</a>

Comment: @Jakub: Look at Quentin's answer, then look at your link. Now look back at the answer. Sadly, your link link does not contain "http://". Try something like `<a href="http://yourdomain.com/mylink.pl">YourDomain.com</a>`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the formatting in my last comment. The links I use is as follows: `<a href="http://www.mylink.pl>SomeName.com</a>`