# I want to add hyperLink in body of email. How can achieve using xamarin forms for android ?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I tried using html from c# and opening email app. But it does not render in email app. How can i achieve this. Please, help me out. And thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Links does not work in <a href> tag when content has .com inside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522616/links-does-not-work-in-a-href-tag-when-content-has-com-inside)

Comment: Are you able to expand on what you are wanting to accomplish? Perhaps edit the question to explain a workflow or a specific need?